# asp.net registration page not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am creating a simple registration page and I get an error which I believe has to do with not being able to find the table I have created, yet I made it locally.

Here is the error I get:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Any help would be fantastic.

Below I have posted the code that I have down so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = userchecker();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = changehere(com);
            conn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Already Exists");
            }

        }
    }

    private string userchecker()
    {
        return "select count(*) from Table where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
    }

    private static int changehere(SqlCommand com)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid NEWguid = Guid.NewGuid();

            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into Table (ID, UserName, Email, Password) values (@ID, @Uname , @email, @password)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", NEWguid.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration successful");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:");
        }
    }

    protected void TextBoxEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your table name..?

Comment: dbo.Table is my table name

Comment: when you get this exception? in userchecker()?

Comment: Why did you tag this as VB.NET and mention VB in your post? I don't see how that's related.

Comment: got the exception in changehere(SqlCommand com)

Comment: having tablenames like `Table` or `Class` or something aren't really good. choose meaningful names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private string userchecker()
{
    return "select count(*) from [Table] where UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
}
```

See the `[]` around `Table`, this is because Table is a reserved word in all SQL variants and you should escape it

Comment: always small.. glad to help !

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the table, table is a reserved word in SQL